# Select input type image when id has a particular pattern

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, find

I have a number of inputs of type file. Their id(s) follow a pattern like this:-
**image_1**, **image_2**, **image_3**, etc.

This wildcard `$('input:file[id^="image_"]')` selects all input type files whose id(s) start with `image_`

The above wildcard has a problem which is, input type file with `id="image_img"` will also get selected.

How can I select input type file whose id starts with `image_` and ends with a numeric value?

Comment: Use a class instead. It's quicker and more semantic and means you won't have this exact same issue when you amend the HTML in future.

Comment: No, can't use a class. Why, I will explain you in the question in the edit section.

Comment: You are probably better off using a different name for the element you don't want to select (i.e. shouldn't start wit 'image_') but on the other hand you can always use not(), e.g. `$('input:file[id^="image_"]:not(#image_img)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct shortcut for this. A good approach, however is to filter out the elements on their IDs:

```
$('input:file[id^="image_"]')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.id.match(/^image_\d+$/);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Select inputs that id start with(`^=`) `image_` and not end with(`.not($=)`) `_img`.

```js
console.log($('input:file[id^=image_]').not('[id$=_img]').get())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="image_1" />
<input type="file" id="image_2" />
<input type="file" id="image_3" />
<input type="file" id="image_img" />
```

Comment: Its a good solution, but suppose there are multiple items with ids like `image_img`, `image_lala`, `image_hula`, etc. In that case, it is a restricted solution.

Comment: Then 31piy's answer would be a better one.

Comment: That's why I said to use a class ;) Doing it this way, ie. exclusive, means that adding another similarly-named field will just break it again. If you make the logic inclusive it's more robust.